# how to make form override the content of layout when scrolling the page

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui

I've used [jScroll](http://www.wduffy.co.uk/jScroll/) to make a scroll element when i scroll the content of page. I have used to scroll other elements like sidebar, it works. But I can not use it to scroll the form search, This is my questions index page:

[a http://s18.postimage.org/5tv1zbjvd/scroll_filter.png](http://s18.postimage.org/5tv1zbjvd/scroll_filter.png)

When i scrolled the page, the form filter search still there and question also. This is my code I used to scroll:

```
<% content_for :head do %>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){ 
            $("#results").pageless( { 
                totalPages: 10,
                url: 'questions/',
                loaderMsg: 'Loading more results'       
             });
            $("#new_question").jScroll({top: 100 });
            $("#import").jScroll({top: 100});
        });
    </script>
<% end %>
```

I have scrolled the sidebar new question and import successful. My form tag search and filter are in `div#search` and `div#filter`. So I wan to ask how can I scroll down the content, these form will go down also and they will be laid above the content of question. You can show me what ever jquery to do, not have to work `jScroll`.

**Update: Add position fixed**

The page display now:

[a http://s8.postimage.org/wq6fya3qd/scroll_filter_error.png](http://s8.postimage.org/wq6fya3qd/scroll_filter_error.png)

**Form**

```
<div class="span7">
        <div class="page-header">
            <%= render 'search' %>
            <%= render 'search_filter' %>
        </div>
        <div id="results">
            <ul class="questions">
                <%= render @questions %>
            </ul>
        </div>
</div>
```

Css:

```
div.page-header {
  position: fixed;
}
```

Comment: not easy to understand exactly what you want. Create a simple html demo in jsffidle.net. You can toggle a class that changes an element to fixed position and make it easier to look at than the bouncing that jScroll creates

Comment: @charlietfl i want the form search and filter go down when i scroll the content down.

Comment: again this is simple with `position:fixed` in css

Comment: @charlietfl it mix the content with question, i will update question.

Comment: without more detail it is very difficult to understand your needs. Look at this for example  http://jsfiddle.net/LsnLa/ Unless you provide some html to work with, and enough basic css , it is hard to visualize your layout

Comment: @charlietfl thanks for example. As i say, these form in div#search and div#filter, in my css, i just put `postion: fixed`

Comment: set `background: white ` to div#search also set `padding-top:` to div#filter

Comment: @charlietfl ,@eicto is there a way i can hide the content of question when these form go down?

Comment: what you mean ? [this](http://jsbin.com/ekifem/1) ?

Comment: @eicto yes, i want it, thanks so much :), can you tell what is this technique called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use css `fixed`,`padding` or `margin` and `background` like  in [this](http://jsbin.com/ekifem/1) example:

Html:

```
 <div id="static">I'm A static header;</div>
  <div id="content">
  <div class="text">I'm a text box</div>
  <div class="text">I'm a text box</div>
  <div class="text">I'm a text box</div>
  <div class="text">I'm a text box</div>
  <div class="text">I'm a text box</div>
  <div class="text">I'm a text box</div>
  <div class="text">I'm a text box</div>
```

CSS:

```
#content {
 padding-top: 100px;
}
#static {
 top: 0px;
 left: 0px;
 font-size: 2em;
 position:fixed;
 width: 100%;
 text-align: center;
 height: 100px;
 border: 1px solid black;
 background: white;
}
.text {
 background: skyblue; 
 font-size: 1.4em;
 height: 1em;
 margin-top: 10px;
 width: 80%;
 text-align: center;
 padding: 20px;
 border-top: 1px solid black;
 margin-left: 10%;
}
```